# Survival Analysis with Time-Varying Covariates and Numerous Cross-Sectional Units

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am seeking clarification regarding how to set up data for survival analysis in R with both time-varying covariates and numerous cross-sectional units. I come from a Stata background and am transitioning to R. However, I have noticed that there are certain aspects of survival analysis set-up in R that are not intuitive to me.

In Stata, you declare your data to be survival-time data by specifying three things: the failure event, the temporal variable, and the cross-sectional unit (so that Stata is not viewing each row in the data as a separate case). I am trying to run a Cox proportional-hazards model. Initially, my understanding is that the syntax should look something like this:

`cox_m1 <- coxph(Surv(time_var, failure_var) ~ X1, robust = TRUE, cluster = country, data = data`

However, when comparing this output to Stata's output for the same model, I found the output to be completely different. I later learned that this was due to the fact that R was not recognizing that my rows in the data set are not independent of one another. For example, I have Cuba in the data set from 1954-1956 which makes up three rows. Simply put, each country-year observation is a unique row. I was unable to find any cluster specification for the Cox model with the survival package. Instead, I found the syntax for running a Cox model with time-varying covariates, which would look like this:

`cox_m2 <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, failure_var) ~ X1, robust = TRUE, cluster = country, data = data`

I generated the tstart and tstop variables grouped by my cross-sectional ID with the following code:

`data <- data %>% group_by(cs_id) %>% mutate(tstart = min(time_count)) %>% mutate(tstop = max(time_count))`

In effect, this means that each tstart value begins at "1" for each unique cross-sectional unit, however, the tstop values are different, dependent on how long a spell lasts prior to a failure event. My main question is whether or not I am using this appropriately. To reiterate, my biggest concern is that I have not found a way to specify cross-sectional units to inform R that each of my rows are not independent. This is the next best thing that I have found, but I am unsure of whether I am even doing the correct thing at all. I understand that this method allows for time-varying covariates, but I am unsure if this code is appropriate for time-varying covariates and different cross-sectional units. I would appreciate any help and I am happy to provide further clarification if needed.

Comment: 1. you need to show some examples of the data, maybe just a little toy dataset you can recreate the problem between stata and R. You also need to show the statistical output. 2. Stata uses "Breslow" method for ties whereas R uses the "Efron" method for ties by default. The Efron method is better. You can get mismatched results with ties. 3. surely the two `data` objects in the first and second line are different. There's no way the results will agree if you're using a long dataset with the same failure variable.

Comment: 3: ctd Recall: in a TVC a covariate change instance requires the failure variable to be set to  0 because the failure had not yet happened. 4. Also in R you have to set cluster = id to get the same frailty as Stata. However doing an unbiased time varying covariate analysis does NOT require you to fit a frailty model. People who think a frailty is required are not considering that a robust hazard function renders a virtually memoryless process when covariates change.